# XSLT stylesheet that makes a copy of an XML document

Tags: xml, xslt

Write an XSLT stylesheet that makes a copy of an XML document. The source document has element and attribute names in uppercase. The output document should be an exact copy, with the exception that element and attribute names are lowercased. For example, it should convert:

```
<p>
<BODY ATTRIBUTE="TheValue">
<H1>Hello world</H1>
</BODY>

into

<body attribute=”TheValue”>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Transform a document to itself, lowercasing all tag names -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- Import the identity transformation -->
    <!-- Whenever you match any node or any attribute -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <!-- Copy the current node -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- Including any attributes it has and any child nodes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Whenever you match any node or any attribute -->
    <!-- When you match any element -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- Create the same element with a lowercase name -->
        <xsl:element name="{translate(name(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}">
            <!-- Including any attributes it has and any child nodes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Because I'm not doing it for attributes. You need to tweak it. The answer is right in front of you.